# Check whether field extension is splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am trying to solve an exercise on Galois theory and it asks whether $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3}, i\sqrt{2})$ is a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$. I wasn't able to show that it is not so I try to show that it is indeed a splitting field. My idea is to find a primitive element of this extension (I believe the sum of the two elements will suffice) and then try to calculate the minimal polynomial of that primitive element.

Is that correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a splitting field because it only contains one of the three roots of $x^3-3$. To get the other two roots, the field would need to contain $\sqrt{-3}$ (or equivalently, a third root of unity $\omega$) which it doesn't contain.

Comment: Alright but, how do you prove that $i\sqrt{3}$ is not contained?

Comment: Your field has degree 6 over $\mathbb{Q}$ since it is generated by one root of $x^3-3$ and one root of $x^2+2$. So it can not have a degree-4 field as a subfield. So $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2},\sqrt{-3})$ can not be a subfield (which it would be, if $\sqrt{-3}$ were in your field).